# In ios8 popover content hide behind navigation bar

Tags: ios8, uipopovercontroller, xcode6

In ios8 popover content hide behind navigation bar although in ios7 it work fine

i am not getting why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, and I was able to sole it with the following code:

```
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myNewCollectionViewController];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
self.myNewCollectionViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeRight;
```

(The UIRectEdgeTop is removed from the edgesForExtendedLayout mask by this piece of code.)